# Want to convert from character format to number format with decimal

Tags: sql, oracle

want to convert character format (00001000000) as 10000.00. Please help me.

I've already tried with

```
select to_number('00012300','9999999999.99','nls_numeric_characters = ''.,''') from dual
```

this script but it can show only 12300, actually i want to view as 123.000

Comment: It is quite unclear what the expected result is... it seems more legit to convert `00012300` to `12300`. If you need `123000` , just multiply by 10...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can convert your value to a number using

```
select to_number('00012300') from dual;
```

It seems that you divide by 100.

So

```
select to_number('00012300') / 100 from dual;
```

If you want to **display** two decimals, back to a varchar again, with a format

```
select to_char(to_number('00012300') / 100, '999999D99')  from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you simply may use, is a workaround like that:

```
CAST(round(0000000111100 / 100, 2) AS numeric(38, 2))
```

So what you do is that you round your value by 2 decimal places while dividing by 100 and then casting it to to a numeric with a 2 piece left-over.

If your value is a string, just simply convert it to an integer before.

Peace